# VM on Windows 7 Virtual PC cannot access host’s DVD Drive

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machines, virtualization, windows-virtual-pc

I have a brand new clean machine with Windows 7 Professional 64bit and I've installed the patch that adds Windows Virtual PC (Windows6.1-KB958559-x64). 
I then go to Windows Virtual PC, create a new Virtual Machine. As soon as go to settings and try to map the VM DVD drive to the host's DVD drive I get "File may be in use by another process or you may not have sufficient access privilege".
I am an administrator in that box...
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's embarrassing... All I needed to do was to run it as Administrator and I had access to my DVD Drive.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a similar problem was resolved by eliminating RDP from the equation.

I use a laptop and a desktop machine, with the desktop hosting a virtual machine. I was trying to share my desktop's DVD drive with its virtual machine and getting the same error message; however, I was doing all of this connected from laptop to desktop via a Remote Desktop Connection.

Accessing the desktop machine in person (and then booting the virtual machine directly) gains me the sufficient access privileges.